# Google Chrome Extension include Jquery and another custom javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to making Chrome Extensions. So I don't know where to start. Tried looking for answers but they don't answer mine.

So basically I need JQuery and also my own custom javascript file(customfile.js) to be executed at the same time whenever a user clicks on my extension icon. The customfile will use the JQuery functions from the JQuery file to call an ajax api.

This is my manifest.json.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "Example",
  "description": "Example",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js","customfile.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
     "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "customfile.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

For some reason some developers left out the "background", and some left out the "content_scripts". Which is correct, or do I need both?

Also, I've read about programmatic injection. Is my code correct in such a way that it will only run both files when only needed? Where do I put this code into, my customfile.js or jquery.js?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-3.2.1.min.js" }, function() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "customfile.js" });
});
```

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: If you are only using a background script, you nearly always should not be loading jQuery. jQuery is primarily about DOM manipulation, in the background script it's unusual for you to be doing any of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `content_scripts` property or use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` if you want to inject code in web pages.
It seems that you're not looking for that, you only need a background script.

And to respond to icon clicks, add this listener to one of your background scripts:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
      ....
});
```

[HERE](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) you can find the documentation for the manifest. It explain what each property in the manifest file does.

Comment: noted. Where do i put this code into, jquery.js or customfile.js, or both?

Comment: Beware, browserAction.onClicked only works if there's no default_popup in manifest.json

Comment: @LegendDemonSlayer You should put this in the "customfile.js" if that is the file that contains your code.

Comment: @LegendDemonSlayer Think of the `"background": {
    "scripts": ...` array just like `<script>` elements in a HTML file, their order matters.